# Is this a Run-ON Sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses, run-on-sentences

Sentence that needs correction :

> "*The Americans* and *The Bostonians* are two Henry James novels , the film versions of which have been as successful as the book versions".

Isn't this a run on sentence with 2 subjects and no conjunction to link the two independent clauses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for a conjunction; the second clause is not independent but a subordinate relative clause modifying *novels*:

> ... the film versions ***of which*** have been ...

This is a common inversion of the ‘canonical’ order

> ... of which the film versions have been ...

Answer (score 0):

"Of which" is a relative pronoun-a linker of dependent and independent clauses. One dependent clause + one independent clause does not equal a fragment but rather a sentence.